# I'd like to build my own garage Olympic lifting platform, but can it support a car?

Tags: wood, garage

I have a converted carport to garage, with an unfinished but smooth concrete surface.  I'm slowly building up my home gym, and I'm interested in options as far as flooring goes. I'd like to build a lifting platform, not unlike these:

[Chris Duffin's Platforms](https://instagram.com/p/5igBFmRnip/?taken-by=kabuki_strong)

The challenge here lies in when I park the car-I'd have to run over the platform.  My car would undoubtedly damage any normal platform.  I could just make portable ones easily, but I'd like to entertain 'finished', permanent options.

I have a couple ideas:

- Construct a metal frame that houses three different sections of material that can be removed or repaired easily.  Before pulling my car in, I could remove and store the platform sections.
- Create a strong 'cover', that the car drives over.  When I pull my car out to train, I would remove the cover, revealing an in-ground platform.  In ground platforms look like this: [Flush Platform](http://www.medxspineprogram.com/Img/Brownsburg%20High%20School-0001.jpg/)

Thoughts?

Comment: Your first link doesn't say what the platform is made of -- is it made of thin material so it's "springy", or is it make of something like 3/4" plywood that could be shored up with wood beams parallel to the wheels? My dad made a pair of work ramps years ago using 1/2" plywood and 3 2x6's parallel to to the wheels (with about 6" between them so the car wheel is always supported by at least 2 of the 2x6's), and he still uses them to change the oil on his 4000 lb pickup.

Comment: Typically it's two layers of 3/4 plywood, then something fancier on top of that.

Comment: What specifically is your concert about driving the car over it? I don't see anything in that link that looks fragile.

Comment: Driving a car on top of the platform will eventually result in deformation of the rubber or wood.

Comment: Those platforms look pretty sturdy, I doubt a car will have any effect. Certainly not on a sheet of plywood. Frankly a full set of weights and a couple people lifting is probably a higher concentration of weight than a car.

Comment: Of course, there's the obvious structural question, but then there's another one about oil drips.  Not all cars are oil-tight, especially as certain seals get old.  Is yours?  And what if it does drip on your platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build the platform as Chris Duffin did, make sure it is low enough so your auto's undercarriage will clear, and leave a couple channels/slots for your auto to pass through. You could make hinged lids that fold back down when the car is gone, giving you a continuous level platform surface. Keep it simple.